# start method after response iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've two method in the same function.
I want to let start the second method only if I have the response of the first method.
How I can do that?

```
     - (void)share:(UIImage*)immagine
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                                 parameters:nil
                                 HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                          completionHandler:^(
                                              FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error
                                              ) {

                             if (!error) {
                               //Here I'm getting a var but it need time 
                                     }

                          }];


     NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(immagine) forKey:@"picture"];

        //that's the var I need

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", result] 
            parameters:params
            HTTPMethod:@"POST"
            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,result,NSError *error)
                                                   {

                                                       if (error==nil)
                                                       {

                                                    }

                                  }];
```

Comment: Did you have a look on NSCondition?

Comment: If use NSCondition or NSLock (or mutex/dispatch_semafore_t/dispatch_group_t/etc) you lock thread, from which call this method. Just put your code which use `result` in same place with _//Here I'm getting a var but it need time_ comment.

Comment: I need to work in the same func. Can you give me an example ? @rock88

Comment: Use completion block for handle finish upload. Sorry, i can't put full code here, link - https://gist.github.com/rock88/ef9ee1936ac47c4b223c

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executing *asynchronously*: it doesn't execute from top to bottom.

Note the order of execution:

**1)** method is called:

```
  - (void)share:(UIImage*)immagine
```

**2)** `startWithGraphPath is called`:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/albums"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {

                         if (!error) {
                           //Here I'm getting a var but it need time 
                                 }

                      }];
```

**3)** The rest of this code is executed straight away:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(immagine) forKey:@"picture"];

    //that's the var I need

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/photos", result] 
        parameters:params
        HTTPMethod:@"POST"
        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,result,NSError *error)
                                               {

                                                   if (error==nil)
                                                   {

                                                }

                              }];
```

**4)** This bit is called once the network request comes back (even though you have to scroll up to see it):

```
completionHandler:^(
                                      FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error
                                      ) {

                     if (!error) {
                       //Here I'm getting a var but it need time 
                             }

                  }];
```

Put the code from step **3)** into the `completionHandler` basically: until that code is hit, the data isn't available.

Comment: If I put the code of step "3" inside: `if (!error) { //Here I'm getting a var but it need time }` become a difficult to read code.. I'm looking for other solution..